# org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists

Tags: hibernate

1. EmpInformation file contains the `<composite-id>` tag having many-to-one with Department Class.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="EmpInformation" table="emp_info" >

        <composite-id name="id" class="info">
               <key-property name="XXXid" type="int">
                    <column name="xxxid" />
               </key-property>
          <key-property name="AAA" type="string">
                    <column name="aaa" length="50" />
               </key-property>
               <key-property name="BBB" type="string">
                    <column name="bbb" length="50" />
               </key-property>
        </composite-id>

        <many-to-one name="Dept" class="Department" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
                    <column name="AAA" length="50" not-null="true" />
               <column name="BBB" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

2. Department class having some more mapping many-to-one and some properties.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Department" table="dept_table">

        <composite-id name="id" class="deptId">

      <key-property name="AAA" type="string">
                <column name="aaa" length="50" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="BBB" type="string">
                <column name="bbb" length="50" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>

     <many-to-one name="Store" class="DepartmentStore" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="AAA" length="50" not-null="true" />
       <column name="BBB" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>

        <property name="ReportId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="report_id" />
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My Questions is whenever I am trying to call the ReportID on getDepartment it's giving error as org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: 
It seems I am not getting the Department info.

1. List a  = createCriteria(EmpInformation.class);
2. Integer I = a.getDepartment().getReportID();

This is the stmt we are using to access the Dept information:

```
<many-to-one name="Dept" class="Department" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
```

I want to point some more info here

1. Lazy is true by default so whenever I access the child table entity it should get that info but it won't.
2. It's mandatory update="false" insert="false" if I remove then it's asking me to put that.

I looks like data issue but still not able to find what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a data issue. Whenever you're trying to retrieve data from a child by passing parent table column id, same data for id which should be available in child table. Otherwise you will get the error as ObjectNotFound Exception.